# String Whitespace ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stringr

I am trying to create a forest plot using ggplot2.

[image]

In my y-axis text, I would like all of the numbers after the whitespace to left align. This is not working.

I know the strings align:

```
[1]  "COBALT"
[2]  "           HR                            1.03 [0.78, 1.32]"
[3]  "           THA                           1.25 [0.71, 1.99]"
[4]  "           Metasul                       0.99 [0.76, 1.29]"
[5]  "           Serum Msmt? (Y vs N)          0.8 [0.41, 1.38]" 
[6]  "           On Market? (Y vs N)           0.85 [0.46, 1.46]"
[7]  "CHROMIUM"                                                  
[8]  "           HR                            1.15 [0.95, 1.38]"
[9]  "           THA                           1.15 [0.76, 1.63]"
[10] "           Metasul                       0.88 [0.72, 1.06]"
[11] "           Serum Msmt? (Y vs N)          0.77 [0.46, 1.18]"
[12] "           On Market? (Y vs N)           0.76 [0.49, 1.14]"
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Comment: see if supplying a monospaced font the y axis text helps: `theme(axis.text.y=element_text(family="Courier")` (and Serum Msmt's line needs a space)

Comment: The question should be updated to include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.